# Apache NIFI "Execute Processor"

Tags: apache-nifi

Can Apache NIFI "ExecuteSQL Processor" stream large set of select result in chunks say 'x' MB?

Comment: From what I understand it was built for large queries in mind which is why it streams the data. I don't think there is any way to chunk the data. I think chunking or "batching" is reserved specifically for Get and Post processors.

Comment: What's the use case? Are you trying to chunk the query result, and each chunk go into a flow file? rather than one large flowfile?

Answer (score 6):

The ExecuteSQL Processor can "stream" large numbers of rows in the sense that it will stream the data directly to FlowFile content (which will not be held in-memory/heap) so it is very memory efficient. It does not, at this time, chunk the results, though. There is a ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1251 to provide such capabilities, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the QueryDatabaseTable processor which supports chunking by the "Max Rows Per Flow File" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify a limit statement in the SQL itself (along with a sort by ID), pull one batch, get the last ID, pull all >max(id), repeat until done, i.e.

```
                                       Start
                                         |
    UpdateAttr: maxid--------- SQL ... $maxid:isEmpty():ifElse('', 'where id>maxid') order by id limit n
           |_____________________________|
                                         |
                                        do sth
```

it's by # records and not size - but knowing the approx size per record, you can still do it